# Tail event example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

In Durrett's Probability (4th edition), an example of a **tail event** (an event in the tail sigma-field $\bigcap_n \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, \dots)$) is the following: given independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots,$ and
their partial sums $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, the following event is a tail event ([Example 2.5.2](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf)):

$$
\{ \limsup_n S_n > x c_n \}, \; c_n \to \infty.
$$

I understand the high level idea of a tail event (i.e. only depends in the asymptotic behavior of the sum since $c_n$ go to infinity) but I cannot articulate a rigorous explanation. Is there a concrete way to show this?

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty much just like your intuitive explanation. For a any $n$, we can write $$ \frac{S_{n+k}}{c_{n+k}} = \frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{c_{n+k}} + \frac{X_{n+1}+\ldots +X_{n+k}}{c_{n+k}} $$ Then, since the first term converges to zero as $k\to\infty$, we have $$ \limsup_m \frac{S_m}{c_m} = \limsup_{k} \frac{S_{n+k}}{c_{n+k}} = \limsup_k \frac{X_{n+1}+\ldots+X_{n+k}}{c_{n+k}} $$ so is clearly $\sigma(X_{n+1},\ldots)$-measurable.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Why is it obvious that $\limsup_m \frac{S_m}{c_m} = \limsup_k \frac{S_{n+k}}{c_{n+k}}$?

Comment: For any $n$, $\limsup_m x_m = \limsup_{k} x_{n+k}.$ This is because (similarly to the limit) the limsup only depends on the tail of the sequence. It is the upper limit that the sequence reaches infinitely many times: any amount of initial values tells you nothing about what happens infinitely many times.

Comment: How is it guaranteed that $\lim_{k -> \infty} \frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{c_{n+k}} =0$ when $X_i$s may take infinite values. Or are those cases excluded.

Comment: @somitra I would assume that case is excluded in this context. Otherwise the assertion (and not just the proof) is wrong. Consider for instance $X_1$ being zero with 50% probability and $\infty$ the other 50% of the time, and all other $X_i$ zero with 100% probability.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the clarification. I was splitting my hairs for hairs over it for days.

Comment: Isn't lim sup is always a tail event? Why is the 1st part of your explanation even needed?  See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281014/342736 for example.

Comment: @Maverick That shows that the limsup of a sequence of events is in the events’ tail field. I don’t see how this problem (which directly involves limsup of reals, not events) follows immediately from that, but I haven’t thought about it much.